# Как создать подключаемый(экспортируемый) jar файл?

Tags: java

Все пользовались сторонними подключаемыми jar файлами к проекту. Вот возник вопрос: А как собственно его создать? К примеру создать файл которой принимает и выводит строку? Т.е я подключаю свой же jar к проекту, создаю объект и передаю ему строку, а он её же и выводит. Или где можно почитать на данную тему? IDE NetBeans. Спасибо.

Comment: Какой-нибудь учебник по Java уже читали?

Comment: Читайте внимательно. Не просто jar файл, а подключаемый к другим проектам. По сути аналог dll.

Comment: По теме вопроса: собираете свой jar, указываете его в classpath проекта и затем можете использовать свою библиотеку.

Comment: Мда... действительно. Всё оказалось проще чем думал. А не подскажете как скрывается код из jar ? Может видели если попытаться посмотреть на код в подключенных jar, то там видно только объявление, а в теле надпись: Compiled code.